# C# queue process with different inputs

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, queue

I have three listBox1, listBox2, listBox3 stores inputs files.

```
  private void Bitrate()
    {
        //turn listBox into List
        List<String> data = new List<String>(listBox3.Items.Cast<String>());
        //do process for each item in the List
        Parallel.ForEach(data, (item) =>
        {
           System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            ...............
         });

   private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Bitrate();
    }
```

This Bitrate() above only processing each item in ListBox3, I want to let's users choose which listBox they wanna process with Bitrate().
And in my cases, i have like Bitrate() , Bitrate1() ,... so i want to put the job in on queue like for example:

```
Queue:
Bitrate() - listBox2
Bitrate() - listBox1
Bitrate1() - listBox3
```

Now button5 click will begin to run each job in Queue, one by one, in order. I get stuck in this problem for at least a moth... please help me... I'm new to this and trying to learn it by myself which is so much pain...
Now I even wonder about my Bitrate() using Parallel.ForEach, don't know if it can process all items in the listBox or not..

Answer (score 2):

To run each job in Queue For Use The async,await Like:-

```
private async void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{await Task.Run(() =>{
            Bitrate(listBox1);
            Bitrate(listBox2);
            Bitrate(listBox3);
        });
}

 private async void Bitrate(List<...> list)
{
    //turn listBox into List
    List<String> data = new List<String>(list.Items.Cast<String>());
    //do process for each item in the List
    Parallel.ForEach(data, (item) =>
    {
       System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        ...............
     });}
```

I think its use full to you.........

Comment: Thanks you so much ! Your answer give me many ideas. But i also want to know how to let's user put the job in to queue. For example user wanna do Bit() using listBox1 as inputs, and then Up() using listBox3 as inputs...